# Image is not loading because of Location in JSP SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, jsp

[image]
I am trying to display image which is inside my webapp/WEB-INF/images folder. And I am using

```
<c:url value="/images/${product.productId}.png" />
```

To get the image in JSP. But it is not working. Please help me out with this.

Comment: The WEB-INF  folder is not public.  A browser  can't  get  your image when it is inside the WEB-INF folder.

Comment: Then what should be the possible solution for this?

Comment: If you want a browser to be able to request it, then put it outside of the WEB-INF folder.